# Image plane visibility after camera movement

Tags: camera, visibility

I added an image as plane B z=0. Then I added another image as plane X z=0. X is above B as I wanted, X uses B as background image. But when I walk/navigate the camera, X would disappear. Increasing z value slightly doesn't seem to work, I had to increase the value quite drastically, which makes it very messy. Is there a proper way to keep X always above B, after I move the camera ? Thanks !

Comment: Make the Z position of X fractionally more than zero. It sounds as if you've got 'Z-fighting' happening at the moment where Blender can't decide which image to display because they're both in the same position.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes I didn't mention I tried that, but a slight change doesn't seem to work. e.g. z=2, it has to be quite substential. like z=10. But hat makes it quite messy especially with a lot of objects around.

Answer (score 0):

OK I think the issue is the camera x,y rotation. For a 2D image plane, that's not needed. (obviously when you do a camera walk with the mouse, it will invariably rotate slightly)
I just needed to lock the rotation and it's fine.